# Mapping a model to multiple database tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 tables in my datebase, on for national holidays (date,country-id) and one for local holidays (date,town-id). I can't have these two tables merged because the 2nd attribute is a FK to different table in each case.

Because this 2 type of holidays are going to be managed from the same views as if it were one, I want to map those tables into a single rails model (date,id,isNational) where isNational would be a boolean to indicate the type. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a look at polymorphic relationships.

```
Holiday
 # area_type: string, area_id: integer, date: date
 belongs_to :area, :polymorphic => true

Town
  has_many :holidays, :as => area
  belongs_to :country

  def all_holidays
    # array of all holidays, both local and national.
    self.holidays + self.country.holidays
  end

Country
  has_many :holidays, :as => area
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a unique table, named for exemple Holiday, with these attributes:

```
add_column :holidays, :date, :datetime
add_column :holidays, :is_national, :boolean, default: false
```